# delete files in a folder older than x minutes via terminal

Tags: find, ls, rm

I want to repeatedly delete files from a folder that are older than some minutes. the reason behind it is a webcam, that constantly delivers jpegs to a folder. that folder is "watched" by an ftp program which mirrors all changes made - also the deletion.

so I tried

```
find Documents/GoProUpload/* -iname "*.JPG" -ctime +120s -print0 | xargs -0 -n1
```

as well as -atime  and -mtime, but nothing is printed. i also checked the same command without the -ctime parameter and then i get all the files.

I also tried it with -mmin:

```
find Documents/GoProUpload/* -iname "*.JPG" -maxdepth 1 -mmin +2
```

but also nothing. why could that be?

Comment: obviously i would add -delete or -rm if it works ;)

Comment: What version of `find` are you using? I don't think you can specify seconds to `-ctime`. Your other attempt should probably work, but note that it's not the same as the first (since `-maxdepth 1` limits it to just the current directory, though it should be the first option to `find`). Also, I'm not sure if it's intended, but you're likley omitting dot files in your current directory by specifying the glob at the end of `Documents/GoProUpload/`